# Probability of rational points in a circle.

Tags: probability

Let $p$,$q$ be chosen by one from the set $(1, 2^{1/2}, 3^{1/2}, 2, e, \pi)$ with replacement. Now a circle is drawn by taking $(p,q)$ as its centre. The probability that at most two rational points exist on circle is:

My approach was to try and find the radius, but it is not possible since only the centre is given. I looked up the solution and it said:

> Note:- If more than 2 rational points exist on circle then centre will be rational. Hence p, q can be not
>   be rational together.

But there was no proof mentioned. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

**for the note:**
The circle through 3 (non-collinear) rational points has rational center.  Hint: Do the construction of that center from the three points as in Euclid, and see that the coordinates of the center are obtained by solving systems of linear equations with rational coefficients.

Here is the construction... Let $A,B,C$ be the three points.  Let $d$ be the line through the midpoint of $AB$ perpendicular to $AB$.  Let $e$ be the line through the midpoint of $BC$ perpendicular to $BC$.  Then the center is the intersection point of lines $d,e$.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates for the coordinates of the circumcentre

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer you have, the coordinates of the centre cannot be both rational.

The probability that at most two rational points exist on circle = The probability of choosing a centre with atleast one irrational coordinate.

The total number of ways of choosing the coordinates of the centre is $6*6=36$

The total number of ways of choosing a centre $(x,y)$ with atleast one irrational coordinate =  
case $1$ : $x$ is irrational - $4*2=8$

case $2$ : $y$ is irrational - $2 * 4=8$ 

case $3$ : Both are irrational - $4 * 4=16$  
The probability of choosing a centre with atleast one irrational coordinate $=\frac{8+8+16}{36}=\frac{32}{36}=\frac{8}{9}$